# Find the number of ways in which the 7 questions can be attempted so that exactly 2 questions are answered correctly.

Tags: combinatorics

A test consists of 7 multiple choice questions, all of which are to be attempted. Each question contains 4 alternative answers, of which one and only one is correct. Find the number of ways in which the 7 questions can be attempted so that exactly 2 questions are answered correctly.

I have tried to solve it by using $\binom72\cdot 5^3 = 2625$. But the actual answer is $5103$.

Comment: Looks like you are new here. We will be happy to help if you show us what you have done to solve this problem.

Comment: I have tried to solve it by using (7C2)5^3 = 2625. But the actual answer is 5103.

Answer (score 2):

Out of $7$ only $2$ are answered correctly,

These $2$ questions can be chosen in

$\binom{7}{2}$ ways.

Now for the remaining $5$ questions, we cant pick the right choice, so we have $3$ available choices for each question. This can be done in

$3^5$ ways.

So the total number of ways is

$$\binom{7}{2} \cdot 3^5=5103$$

Answer (score 1):

It is $3^5$ instead of $5^3$.

We want to find the number of ways to answer 2 questions correctly and 5 questions wrongly.

To do so, we first select 2 questions out of 7, and answer it correctly. There are $\binom{7}{2}=21$ ways.

Now, there are 5 questions remain. Since we should select the wrong answer, there are 3 choices left for each. So, there are $3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3=3^5=243$ ways.

Hence, by multiplication principle, the total number of ways is $21\cdot243=5103$.